# Python boolean variable, True, False and None

Tags: python

I have a boolean variable named `mapped_filter`.
If I am not wrong, this variable can hold 3 values, either `True`, `False` or `None`.

I want to differentiate each of the 3 possible values in an `if` statement. Is there a better way to achieve that than doing the following?

```
if mapped_filter:
    print("True")
elif mapped_filter == False:
    print("False")
else:
    print("None")
```

Comment: `if mapped_filter is None` unmistakably compares with `None`...

Comment: if you're looking for a `case` statement, I'm sorry, but no, there's not a better way. You still can do crazy things like having a dictionary like `crazy_dict = {True: ..., False:..., None: ...}` and then `crazy_dict[mapped_filter]()`.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. If `mapped_filter` is a boolean, it can only have two different values: `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code anything that's not truthy or `False` prints `"None"`, even if it's something else. So `[]` would go print `None`. If no object other than `True`, `False` and `None` can get there your code is fine.

But in python we generally allow any object to be truthy or not. If you want to do this, a better way would be to do:

```
if mapped_filter is None:
    # None stuff
elif mapped_filter:
    # truthy stuff
else:
    # falsey stuff
```

if you explicitly want to disallow any value that's not a `bool` or `None`, then instead do:

```
if isinstance(mapped_filter, bool):
    if mapped_filter:
        # true stuff
    else:
        # false stuff
elif mapped_filter is None:
    # None stuff
else:
    raise TypeError(f'mapped_filter should be None or a bool, not {mapped_filter.__class__.__name__}')
```

Comment: That was what I was looking to. This approach looks better. Thanks.